# Container read-only mode option

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-secrets

I am implementing docker best practices in our application, so i came across `read_only: true` option in the `docker-compose.yml` file. 
In this method i am getting errors like - `mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/run/apache2': Read-only file system`. 
Is it possible to give read-write permission for some folders, under `read_only: true` option.

Comment: How about using docker image which has these folder already in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following option :

```
docker run -d -p <yourport> -v /var/run/apache2 --read-only <yourimage>
```

the above code will make the `/var/run/apache2` writable to your container.

Add similar exceptions to the `-v list`.

Answer (score 0):

To allows write right in a folder through docker-compose.yml, you can do this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  myservice_name:
    build:
      context: .
    working_dir: /home/myuser
    ports:
      - "1234:1234" # exposed:local
    entrypoint: /etc/run_xinetd.sh
    read_only: true
    volumes:
      - /tmp
```